# Efficient way of assigning dicts to objects in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization, lambda

I'm looking for the most efficient/ python way of solving the following Problem:

I have a list of local objects (`list_a`), a list of objects on a server (`list_b`). `list_b` is a list of dictionaries, not objects.
I want to update some information in the local object with the ones given by the server. The assignment can be done by the attribute `name` or the identifier `'name'`, in the dictionary. Both lists could be a subset of each other.

Here is my current solution with some example data:

```
class Dummy():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
        self._attr = ''

    def __str__(self):
        return "Test-Object[" + self._name + ", " + self._attr + "]"

    def update(self, obj):
        self._attr = obj['attr']

    __repr__ = __str__

list_a = [Dummy(str(x)) for x in xrange(10)] 
list_b = [{'name': str(x), 'attr': str(x*2)} for x in xrange(8, -1, -1)] 

extracted_names_a = [x._name for x in list_a]
extracted_names_b = [x['name'] for x in list_b]
filtered_list_a = (x for x in list_a if x._name in extracted_names_b)
filtered_list_b = (x for x in list_b if x['name'] in extracted_names_a)
sorted_list_a = sorted(filtered_list_a, key=lambda k: k._name)
sorted_list_b = sorted(filtered_list_b, key=lambda k: k['name'])
for obj, d in zip(sorted_list_a, sorted_list_b):
    obj.update(d)

print(list_a)
```

This is just a simple example, in the real world there are 2000+ entries and a little bit more data

Comment: Fyi, I have renamed variable `dict` to `d`. Don't name variables after classes.

Comment: When you say efficient/ python way, what exactly do mean...
Memory efficient? Speed? Do you have a threshold to what efficient enough is?
Basically, what's the context to this question?

Comment: All python dictionnaries have built-in methods called *items* and *iteritems* . You can also instanciate an object using the key-words dictionnary syntax, e.g. Dummy(**myArgsDictionnary) (you would need to add the corresponding attributes in the __init__ arguments)

Comment: @Yftach My solution seems to be overloaded(to me), with the extracted lists, generators and the sorted lists. I'm kind of new to python so maybe there is a more elegant way of doing it. The biggest concern is speed, at the moment.

Comment: Does this code really take even a measurable fraction as long as, e.g., downloading the objects from the server? It seems like you’re trying to micro-optimize code that probably isn’t anywhere near your bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your biggest problem is the filtering. For each element of each list, you’re searching the entire other list to see if it exists. This takes quadratic time. If you convert these objects to sets of names, or dicts keyed by name, you can eliminate that quadratic work and make it log-linear.

After that, the `sorted` is also no longer necessary, and it’s the only reason the code is log-linear, so now it’ll be linear.

While we’re at it, you’re wasting memory, and possibly time, building up a list just to iterate over it in a generator expression in the next line. This becomes even more important if we get rid of the `sorted`, because then we don’t *ever* need a list.

So:

```
dict_a = {x._name: x for x in list_a}
for d in list_b:
    try:
        dict_a[d['name']].update(d)
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

The dict lookup with try/except takes care of filtering out dicts without matching objects, and you don’t need to filter out objects without matching dicts because they just won’t get called.

If there are a lot more dicts than objects, reverse things to make a dict of the dicts and iterate over the objects.

Or, if you can keep the objects in a dict in the first place, instead of keeping them in a list and making a temporary dict just for this code, even the better. And if you can iterate the dicts one by one as you parse then off the server response instead of first building a list of them, you’ll have eliminated all unnecessary large allocations and probably sped things up further.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing your objects in a list, you should convert that list into a dict:

```
objects_by_name = {obj._name: obj for obj in list_a}
```

This lets you look up the object associated with a name in `O(1)` time.

Updating all objects is now as easy as iterating over `list_b`, grabbing the corresponding object from the dict, and calling its `update` method:

```
for dic in list_b:
    obj = objects_by_name[dic['name']]
    obj.update(dic)
```

Overall this has a time complexity of `O(n)`, whereas your code is `O(n log n)` because of the sort.